# Logging lpRect and uFormat from DrawTextA

Tags: python

Using [APIMonitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) from Rohitab I found that DrawTextA has some additional arguments I would like to log using Python and [Pydbg](https://github.com/OpenRCE/pydbg) (I'm currently logging lpchText, se below).

[image: DrawTextA]

My current hooking code looks something like this:

```
def DrawTextHook(dbg, args):
   # Log lpchText
   text = dbg.get_ascii_string(incremental_read(dbg, args[1], 255))
```

The argument I would like to log is **lpRect** and **uFormat**. How do I extend my currrent code to log these two arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you `really` ask me i will say `dump pydbg` and start using `logged ollydbg conditional break points` it will give you the function's arguments cleanly formatted into its components or even windbg

you asked pydbg here is how you can do it in pydbg

```
from pydbg import *
from pydbg.defines import *

def handler_breakpoint (pydbg):   
   if pydbg.first_breakpoint:
    return DBG_CONTINUE

   arg1 =   dbg.get_arg(1,dbg.context)
   arg2 =   dbg.get_arg(2,dbg.context)
   arg3 =   dbg.get_arg(3,dbg.context)
   arg4 =   dbg.get_arg(4,dbg.context)
   arg5 =   dbg.get_arg(5,dbg.context)
   text =   dbg.read_process_memory(arg2,0x20)
   lprect = dbg.read_process_memory(arg4,0x10)

   print "hDc = %08x\nText = %08x %s\nCount = %08x\nlpRect = %08x %s\nuFormat = %08x\n" % (arg1,arg2,pydbg.get_unicode_string(text),arg3,arg4,lprect,arg5)
   return DBG_CONTINUE

dbg = pydbg()
dbg.set_callback(EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT, handler_breakpoint)
dbg.attach(2708)
DrawTextW = dbg.func_resolve("user32", "DrawTextW")
dbg.bp_set(DrawTextW)
pydbg.debug_event_loop(dbg)
```

and an output for calc.exe (uses DrawTextW not A)

C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages>python calc.py

```
hDc = 48010f0d
Text = 000b85fe Sta
Count = ffffffff
lpRect = 0007fa7c         $   ↔
uFormat = 00000025

hDc = 4b010f0d
Text = 000b85fe Sta
Count = ffffffff
lpRect = 0007fa7c         $   ↔
uFormat = 00000025

hDc = 6c010ea9
Text = 000b8668 tan
Count = ffffffff
lpRect = 0007fa7c         $   ↔
uFormat = 00000025

hDc = 79010ea9
Text = 000b8668 tan
Count = ffffffff
lpRect = 0007fa7c         $   ↔
uFormat = 00000025

hDc = 7c010f0d
Text = 000b8688 x^2
Count = ffffffff
lpRect = 0007fa7c         $   ↔
uFormat = 00000025

hDc = 8e010f0d
Text = 000b8688 x^2
Count = ffffffff
lpRect = 0007fa7c         $   ↔
uFormat = 00000025

hDc = ab010ea9
Text = 000b869e 1/x
Count = ffffffff
lpRect = 0007fa7c         $   ↔
uFormat = 00000025

hDc = bf010ea9
Text = 000b869e 1/x
Count = ffffffff
lpRect = 0007fa7c         $   ↔
uFormat = 00000025
```

if you want to change to ollydbg

c:> ollydbg.exe calc.exe

```
alt+e -> select calc.exe -> ctrl+N ->Start typing Draw->select and rightclick ->follow import in disassembler ->shift + f4-> enable radio log function arguments to always 
leave all else to default and hit ok and f9 to run the exe
```

ollydbg will log all the arguments (you can selectively log only args you want also)
like  log only if hDc = XXX and Text == X^2 and Uformat != y

a sample output from ollydbg running calc.ex and loggging function arguments to DrawTextW

```
7E42D7E2   CALL to DrawTextW from calc.010061F1
             hDC = DA011041
             Text = "Sta"
             Count = FFFFFFFF (-1.)
             pRect = 0007FA28 {0.,0.,36.,29.}
             Flags = DT_CENTER|DT_VCENTER|DT_SINGLELINE
7E42D7E2   CALL to DrawTextW from calc.010061F1
             hDC = DB010B34
             Text = "Ave"
             Count = FFFFFFFF (-1.)
             pRect = 0007FA28 {0.,0.,36.,29.}
             Flags = DT_CENTER|DT_VCENTER|DT_SINGLELINE
7E42D7E2   CALL to DrawTextW from calc.010061F1
             hDC = A0010D69
             Text = "Sum"
             Count = FFFFFFFF (-1.)
             pRect = 0007FA28 {0.,0.,36.,29.}
             Flags = DT_CENTER|DT_VCENTER|DT_SINGLELINE
7E42D7E2   CALL to DrawTextW from calc.010061F1
```

With windbg do this

```
bp USER32!DrawTextW ".printf \"Text=%mu\\nRect.L=%x\\nRect.R=%x\\n\",poi(esp+8),poi(poi(esp+10)+8),poi(poi(esp+10)+c);gc"
```

windbg conditinal bp output

```
0:001> g
Text=F-E
Rect.L=24
Rect.R=1d
Text=dms
Rect.L=24
Rect.R=1d
Text=sin
Rect.L=24
Rect.R=1d
Text=cos
Rect.L=24
Rect.R=1d
Text=tan
Rect.L=24
Rect.R=1d
Text=(
Rect.L=24
```